# How to change the opacity of an child element when parent is hovered

Tags: html, css

I want to change the child div image opacity when the parent div is hovered. How to do this in CSS?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <img src="" alt="" height="" width="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't tell me that you found absolutely nothing when doing a search? https://www.google.com/search?ei=dcBNW9e2OZCKapzmr-gE&q=change+opacity+of+element+css&oq=change+opacity+of+element+css&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.11607.12210.0.12578.8.6.0.0.0.0.278.657.0j1j2.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.1.278....0.y2MQJmAzjnM

Comment: @TemaniAfif how can the accepted answer that has no snippet, no explanation, and is for this level of question difficulty get 75points is beyond me. Plus it doesn't even answer the question exactly. `change the child div image opacity when the parent div is hovered` which should translate in `.parent:hover .child img { opacity: 0.7 } `

Comment: @MihaiT good luck finding the upvoters that are encouraging such trivial and obvious question to be asked again and again and again ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [:hover-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and change the img [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

```
.child:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Or if you want to change opacity of the while child div then:

```
.parent:hover .child {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Fiddle Link - [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0zwfkr17/26/)

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green
}
.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: .5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.parent {
    background: red;
    padding: 30px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
   opacity: 0.3
}

.child {
    background: blue;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <img src="" alt="" height="" width="">
    </div>
</div>
```